# Что значит 64h?

Tags: winapi, ассемблер

```
.text:00401590 sub_401590      proc near               ; DATA XREF: .rdata:0040245C↓o
.text:00401590                 push    esi
.text:00401591                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:00401593                 call    ?OnInitDialog@CDialog@@UAEHXZ ; CDialog::OnInitDialog(void)
.text:00401598                 mov     eax, [esi+20h]
.text:0040159B                 push    0               ; lpTimerFunc
.text:0040159D                 push    64h             ; uElapse
.text:0040159F                 push    3               ; nIDEvent
.text:004015A1                 push    eax             ; hWnd
.text:004015A2                 call    ds:SetTimer
.text:004015A8                 push    0               ; int
.text:004015AA                 lea     ecx, [esi+64h]  ; this
.text:004015AD                 mov     dword ptr [esi+60h], 0
.text:004015B4                 call    ?EnableWindow@CWnd@@QAEHH@Z ; CWnd::EnableWindow(int)
.text:004015B9                 mov     eax, 1
.text:004015BE                 pop     esi
.text:004015BF                 retn
.text:004015BF sub_401590      endp
```

Что делает данный кусок кода ?

Comment: 64h = 100 в десятичной системе. [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) создает таймер с указанной задержкой в миллисекундах.

Comment: то есть uElapse  задает интервал , и какой этот интервал ? 100 чего ? или 64h чего ? секунд или миллисекунд

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз мой комментарий выше.

Answer (score 2):

`64h` - это число в 16-ричной системе. `64h = 6*16 + 4 = 100` в десятичной системе. Можно в IDA Pro (очевидно, что вы скопировали код оттуда) щелкнуть на число `64h` и нажать клавишу `h` - отображение числа переключится на десятичную систему.

По поводу единиц - смотрим документацию к функции [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx):

> uElapse [in] Type: UINT
>
> The time-out value, in **milliseconds**.
>
> If uElapse is less than USER_TIMER_MINIMUM (0x0000000A), the timeout
>   is set to USER_TIMER_MINIMUM. If uElapse is greater than
>   USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM (0x7FFFFFFF), the timeout is set to
>   USER_TIMER_MAXIMUM.